# How to call the onSubmit event of formio programatically?

Tags: reactjs, formio

I have a button on which I want to call the onSubmit event of formio. How can we call formio submit event programatically?

I read the formio documentation but didn't find anything. I tried searching the stackoverflow and read multiple Q&A but didn't find anything that can help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.